# how to reply the email from professor?

Tags: etiquette

I want to say got it, but it seems not appropriate.
Can I just reply like, well noted with thanks or well received?
How to reply emails like this?

thanks in advance
EDIT----------------------------------
I work as the TA for the professor. So the usual cases are: 
1. he gives me an assignment and I want to reply 'I will do it right away'.
2. I ask him some questions about the assignment and he replies something. And I want to express 'yes, got it!'

Comment: Depends on the content of the email you received. Was it to indicate a letter of reference had been sent, that he received you assignment, to encourage you to attend class....the list goes on.

Answer (score 2):

> He gives me an assignment and I want to reply 'I will do it right away'.

Then reply: "I will do it right away".

But if you're going to do it right away, you can probably wait replying until you have finished the assignment, if a reply in that case is expected.

> I ask him some questions about the assignment and he replies something. And I want to express 'yes, got it!'

Then reply: "Got it, thanks."

To sum up: as many students, you're overthinking all this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found (through trial and error) that a simple "My sincere thanks" can work wonders.